# Redirect output/logs to file in pipelined commands

Tags: powershell, redirect, pipe, export-to-csv

I have the below command where I am trying to get output redirected for both commands before and after the pipe. 
But this creates csv file with no data.

(some-command) > $log file | export-csv $csvpath >> $logfile

But when I run the command as below, data is returned

(some-command)| export-csv $csvpath >>$logfile

I want a way where I can redirect output for both commands in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to use [Tee-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) to pass output to a file and down the pipeline at the same time. You can also use ; to separate statements without needing a new line. Here's an example using both:

```
(get-date | Tee-Object -FilePath $logfile | Export-Csv $csvpath) ; gc $csvpath >> $logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Tee-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849937.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which should be pretty close to that what you want